# Deformed sprites in line renderer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create rectangle using line renderer (*corner vertices is set to 0, texture mode to tile, wrap mode for texture to repeat*), but sprites are deformed:
[image: deformed sprites in line renderer]

Material is simple (URP/Unlit with Tiling X:1 Y:1)
When I set corner vertices to value greater then 0, then it looks good, but without corners:
[image: nondeformed sprite in line renderer but without corners]

How to setup line renderer to draw sprite (dots) also in corners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line renderer doesn't generate the right type of topology for your use case.

[image: Comparison between the Unity line renderer topology and the desired square face topology. Two squares with holes in the middle with different geometries on the corners. The faces of the left mesh are trapezoid and the faces of the right are perfect squares]

It's a bit more tricky, but you'll have much better control if you generate your own [mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) with your own UV.

Comment: Thank you! That make sense, I will play around with mesh! :)